# codeigniter application works on hostgator but not another web host

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter application that is working perfectly on my hostgator hosted domain.

I have configured .htaccess and config.php to remove the index.php from the URL. As mentioned this is working 100%. I now need to move the application from my hostgator server to a local server in South Africa with Afrihost.

the modified htaccess and config file are shown below:

**my htaccess file is:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Prevent CI index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

# Prevent user access to the CI system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] 

# Prevent user access to the CI application folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and my config.php file is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://logicoportal.co.za';
$config['index_page'] = '';
// let me know if you need to see any other setting
```

When I try to browse to the domain http://www.logicoportal.co.za I get error `This page can't be displayed`.

If I browse to my ion auth controller, http://logicoportal.co.za/auth/login I get 404 error `The webpage cannot be found`.

If I browse to my full codeigniter default path, http://logicoportal.co.za/index.php/auth/login I get error `This page can't be displayed`

I am assuming it is an htaccess configuration error however I am not sure how to correct this. read many an article with no luck. Alternatively is there another config setting in codeigniter to support this?

I have spoken to the new hosting company, Afrihost and they say they cannot help in this regard.

Any advice / direction would be appreciated.

Thanks as always.

Comment: I agree its probably an htaccess problem. What are the differences in server specifications (apache,php version etc)? Can you access any web page on the server? What if you try to access just /index.php or add a simple /index.html file? Even if your support won't support you they could provide your apache config and/or error logs.

Comment: Is mod rewrite enabled on another web host??

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting in your index.php file? Also, what kind of routes have you set up?

Comment: Apache Version is 2.2.23 for both servers. PHP version on old server is 5.2.17 and the new one is 5.3.20. Thanks

Comment: Routes is standard, just the standard. `$route['default_controller'] = "auth";
$route['404_override'] = '';`

Comment: error reporting is for all but nothing outputted: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: If I browse to the link in firefox, `No input file specified. ` is displayed which is just page not fond in IE. I can however browse directly to http://logicoportal.co.za/index.php/auth/login it does work but on login attempt is rerouted to `No input file specified. ` obviously. mod rewrite is enabled on the server so must be my .htaccess file. thanks all for your time but any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working Solution:
htaccess file to remove index.php on shared hosting server

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) ./index.php [L]
```

Comment: @Smudger Thanks for this solution, It was freaking me out. But your solutions worked well

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `?` in:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1
```

So it's:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time. I did try this with no change. any other ideas? thanks,