# How to remove index.php from url using .htaccess on linux server in codeigniter?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

My project work on local successfully but not working on my server i have a Linux server hosting in hostgator

default controller is works fine but for example:

`example.com/contact-us` is not working it will redirect to server's 404 page not found page but `example.com/index.php/contact-us` is working

my .htaccess code is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

config:

```
$config['base_url']     = 'http://linksture:2000/websitebusinessforsale.com/project';
$config['index_page']   = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

I don't know whats the problem, thank you in advance for your reply

Comment: Posible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217862/codeigniter-application-works-on-hostgator-but-not-another-web-host

Comment: @tomexsans not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that the code you have is inside a folder from the apache root. If that is the case, you need to write

```
/project/index.php/$0
```

So if you have uploaded all your code into /var/www/myproject, then use

```
/myproject/index.php/$0
```

Comment: i cant understand you what to write in place of /project?

Answer (score 0):

I know maybe you find the solution for this problem,
the problem is in Apache config.

First, find the config file, (in my case, i use Linux Mint)
the config file should be under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

Continue to edit the `default.conf` file (it depend on your machine, in my my machine it named `000-default.conf`)
Edit the file by using this command `sudo gedit 000-default.conf`

Put this command outside the virtual tag

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Save and restart your apache using `sudo service apache2 restart`

So, you have to find the apache config files on your machine, then do the same steps.